# Non trivial powers

Tags: code-golf, math

Write the shortest program to print the non-trivial powers ≤ 2^12 in order

non-trivial power means the base and exponent are > 1

Leading whitespace is optional
When there are multiple solutions, the order is not important, so

`16 = 4^2, 2^4` is ok

Sample output:

```
      4 = 2^2
      8 = 2^3
      9 = 3^2
     16 = 2^4, 4^2
     25 = 5^2
     27 = 3^3
     32 = 2^5
     36 = 6^2
     49 = 7^2
     64 = 2^6, 4^3, 8^2
     81 = 3^4, 9^2
    100 = 10^2
    121 = 11^2
    125 = 5^3
    128 = 2^7
    144 = 12^2
    169 = 13^2
    196 = 14^2
    216 = 6^3
    225 = 15^2
    243 = 3^5
    256 = 2^8, 4^4, 16^2
    289 = 17^2
    324 = 18^2
    343 = 7^3
    361 = 19^2
    400 = 20^2
    441 = 21^2
    484 = 22^2
    512 = 2^9, 8^3
    529 = 23^2
    576 = 24^2
    625 = 5^4, 25^2
    676 = 26^2
    729 = 3^6, 9^3, 27^2
    784 = 28^2
    841 = 29^2
    900 = 30^2
    961 = 31^2
   1000 = 10^3
   1024 = 2^10, 4^5, 32^2
   1089 = 33^2
   1156 = 34^2
   1225 = 35^2
   1296 = 6^4, 36^2
   1331 = 11^3
   1369 = 37^2
   1444 = 38^2
   1521 = 39^2
   1600 = 40^2
   1681 = 41^2
   1728 = 12^3
   1764 = 42^2
   1849 = 43^2
   1936 = 44^2
   2025 = 45^2
   2048 = 2^11
   2116 = 46^2
   2187 = 3^7
   2197 = 13^3
   2209 = 47^2
   2304 = 48^2
   2401 = 7^4, 49^2
   2500 = 50^2
   2601 = 51^2
   2704 = 52^2
   2744 = 14^3
   2809 = 53^2
   2916 = 54^2
   3025 = 55^2
   3125 = 5^5
   3136 = 56^2
   3249 = 57^2
   3364 = 58^2
   3375 = 15^3
   3481 = 59^2
   3600 = 60^2
   3721 = 61^2
   3844 = 62^2
   3969 = 63^2
   4096 = 2^12, 4^6, 8^4, 16^3, 64^2
```

Comment: There's a lot of powers missing here; what about 21^3 etc?
What is your definition of "non-trivial powers"?

Comment: Is it also possible to print multiple lines with the same number on the left, if there are multiple solutions?

Comment: @hallvabo, oops haven't had coffee yet this morning. fixed it now

Comment: @FUZxxl, you have to put the multiple solutions on the same line, although for interest please submit the alternative version too if the requirement makes a large difference in your language

Comment: +1 when I get more votes :-)

Comment: How strict is the output format? Are the spaces needed? Are the left-hand numbers needed?

Comment: @J B, Just the (padding) leading spaces are optional. Extra trailing spaces would be ok too. The spaces around the `=` and after the `,` are required

Comment: @Joey, fixed that. base and exponent are > 1

Comment: May we return a list of strings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Ruby 1.9, <del>112 111</del> 99 characters

```
4097.times{|x|s=[]
2.upto(64){|a|2.upto(12){|b|a**b==x&&s<<[a,b]*?^}}
puts [x,s*", "]*" = "if s[0]}
```

This takes about 0.8 seconds to complete on my system. A faster solution is 111 characters long:

```
h={};(2..64).map{|a|(2..12).map{|b|a**b<4097&&(h[a**b]||=[])<<[a,b]*?^}}
puts h.sort.map{|a,b|[a,b*", "]*" = "}
```

Answer (score 7):

### Python, 113

```
R=range
for k in R(4097):
 v=', '.join(`i`+'^'+`j`for i in R(2,65)for j in R(2,13)if i**j==k)
 if v:print k,'=',v
```

This takes a few seconds to complete.
A faster (148 chars) version, using a dictionary to avoid the outermost loop, runs in ~ 0.01 sec:

```
R=range(2,65)
p={}
for i in R:
 for j in R:
    if i**j<4097:p[i**j]=p.get(i**j,[])+[`i`+'^'+`j`]
for k,v in sorted(p.items()):print k,'=',', '.join(v)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the equals sign is required for the output, though that shouldn't change the code size by much.

Comment: Whops, I accidentally removed it when I got rid of the (optional) leading whitespace. Fixed it!

Answer (score 4):

### Windows PowerShell, 102

With help by Ventero for the initial code.

```
$OFS=', '
4..4KB|%{$x=$_
if($s=2..64|%{$a=$_
2..12|?{[math]::pow($a,$_)-eq$x}|%{"$a^$_"}}){"$x = $s"}}
```

Answer (score 4):

### <s>Interactive</s> J, <s>118</s> <s>101</s> 98

```
3 :0"0 i.4097
if.#l=.":2j2+63(<.@%~j.|)I.y=,^/~2+i.63
do.echo(":y),' = ',l rplc j`^,' ';', 'end.
)
```

(last newline unneeded)

Still a lot of code for the presentation...

Note: in theory changing `63` and `63` to `y` and `y` saves 2 more bytes but that version uses extreme amount of memory.

*Edited by randomra.*

Comment: Using [space]j[backtick]^,' ';', ' instead of  `'j';'^';' ';', '` saves 3 bytes. (Given up formatting it...)

Comment: @randomra You've got edit rights; please go ahead! (I can't find a box with J to verify with my current setup, and I'm in kind of in a hurry). This would make J the best of the show, it would be a pity not to show it off! :-)

Answer (score 3):

### Bash, 138 chars

```
i=2;j=1
f(){((v>4096))&&((j=1,++i))
a[$v]+="$i^$j, "
((v=i**++j,i<65))&&f
}
f
f(){
echo $j = ${a[$j]}
((j++<v))&&f
}
f|sed '/=$/d;s/.$//'
```

#### Edits

- **(169 : 155)** 2 `for` for a `while`.
- **(155 : 148)** Append with `+=`
- **(148 : 147)** output with `while`, reusing j
- **(147 : 142)** use sed to remove empty lines
- **(142 : 137)** put `v` in `(())`, use v for 4096 (last value)
- **(137 : 134)** remove sed quotes, join `(())` expressions
- **(134 : 132)** replace loops with recursive functions
- **(132 : 142)** forgot the comma `,` :(
- **(142 : 138)** tired of updates :p

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, 138 characters - [Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/DszyND.php53)

```
<?for($b=1;++$b<65;)for($e=1;++$e<13;)if(4097>$f=pow($b,$e))$p[$f][]="$b^$e";ksort($p);foreach($p as$n=>$c)echo"$n = ".join($c,", ")."\n";
```

**Ungolfed**

```
<?php

// Array of combinations

$powers = array();

// Loop through every base from 2 to 64, as 64 is the highest you can go

for($base = 2; $base < 65; $base++){

    // Loop through all powers from 2 to 12, as 12 is the maximum

    for($power = 2; $power < 13; $power++){

        // Calculate the power

        $end = pow($base, $power);

        // Kill the loop if the result is too high

        if($end > 4096){
            break;
        }

        // Add the combination if the result is within limits

        $powers[$end][] = $base."^".$power;
    }
}

// Sort the powers by the total amount

ksort($powers);

// Output the powers in the correct format

foreach($powers as $number => $combinations){
    echo $number." = ".implode($combinations, ", ")."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python, 127 chars

```
F={}
for i in range(693):a,b=i/11+2,i%11+2;F[a**b]=F.get(a**b,'')+', %d^%d'%(a,b)
for k in sorted(F)[:81]:print k,'=',F[k][2:]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 152 byte

```
Print/@Cases[Range@4096,n_/;(2<=##&&##==##&)@@(f=#2&@@@FactorInteger@#&)@n:>{n,Row[{n^(1/#),#}~Row~"^"&/@Reverse@Rest@Divisors@#,", "]&@@f@n}~Row~" = "]
```

This got embarrassingly long. Something like 25 characters are spent on output formatting. The actual code is fairly simple: filter those numbers where all exponents in the prime factorisation are equal. Then, for each of those produce one result for each divisor of the exponent (excluding 1, including itself).

Answer (score 1):

## OCaml + Batteries, <strike>220</strike> <strike>206</strike> <strike>158</strike> 156 characters

Taking a hint from the best-scored solutions:

```
Printf.(iter(fun x->match
String.join", "[?List:sprintf"%d^%d"b e|b<-2--64;e<-2--12;float
x=float b**float e?]with""->()|s->printf"%5d = %s\n"x s)(4--4096))
```

(Line endings at significative whitespace to keep lines short.) A faster but longer version that generates powers instead of testing them:

```
Printf.(List.(iter(fun l->printf"%5d = %s\n"(fst(hd l))(String.join", "(map
snd l)))(group(fun(x,_)(y,_)->x-y)[?List:truncate p,sprintf"%d^%d"b
e|b<-2--64;e<-2--12;p<-List:[float b**float e];p<=4096.?])))
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 160

```
o={}
i=2
s=''
n=4097
for(k=4;k<n;k=++i*i)for(j=2;k<n;k*=i)
{a=i+'^'+j
if(o[k])o[k]+=', '+a
else o[k]=a
j++}for(i=0;i<n;i++)if(o[i])s+='\n'+i+' = '+o[i]
alert(s)
```

#### 194

```
o={},i=2,s='',n=4096
for(k=4;k<=n;k=i*i){for(j=2;k<=n;k*=i){o[k]=o[k]||[]
o[k].push(i+'^'+j)
j++}i++}
for(i=0;i<n;i++){if(o[i]){s+='\n'+i+' = '
for(j in o[i])s+=(j==0?'':', ')+o[i][j]}}
alert(s)
```

Comment: Rolled back; please post golfing suggestions as comments, not edits.

Answer (score 1):

### C (589 bytes)

```
int pow(int a,int b){
   int res = 1;
   while(b>0){
    while(b%2 == 0){
        a *= a; b/=2;
    }
    b--;
    res = res*a;
}
return res;
}
char s[99],t[9];

int main(){
   int N,T,a,i,f,e,n;
  for(n = 2; n <= 1<<12; n++){
      strcpy(s,"");
      T = N = n;
      f = 0;
      int sqt = sqrt(N)+1;
      for(i = 2; i <= sqt; i++){
         for(e=0;0==N%i;e++,N/=i);
           for(a = i; e > 1;e = e%2?(e+1)/2:e/2)
              for(a=i;a<T;pow(a,e)==T?f++?0:printf("%d =",T),sprintf(t,", %d^%d",a,e),strcat(s,t):0,a*=i);
    }
    f?puts(s+1):0;
   }
   return 0;
 }
```

I didn't golfed also this approach is not the best one but yet fast enough to produce an exact 0s in [ideone](http://ideone.com/6P8NS).

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 146 characters

```
c[a]=a
c(a:z)=a++", "++c z
n#[]=""
n#s=shows n$" = "++c s++"\n"
main=putStr$(\n->n#[shows x$'^':show y|x<-[2..64],y<-[2..12],x^y==n])=<<[4..4096]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 39 bytes

```
jm++^Fhd" = "j", "jL\^d<.g^Fk^tS64 2 81
```

Try it online [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jm%2B%2B%5EFhd%22%20%3D%20%22j%22%2C%20%22jL%5C%5Ed%3C.g%5EFk%5EtS64%202%2081&debug=0).

```
jm++^Fhd" = "j", "jL\^d<.g^Fk^tS64 2 81
                               S64       [1-64]
                              t          Discard first element
                             ^     2     Cartesian product of the above with itself
                        .g               Group the pairs, as k, using:
                          ^Fk              [a,b] -> a^b
                       <             81  Take the first 81 results of the above (those where exponential <= 4096)
 m                                       Map the remaining groups, as d, using:
                  jL\^d                    Join each pair in d on "^"
             j", "                         Join on ", "
  +     " = "                              Prepend " = "
   +^Fhd                                   Prepend the result of the exponent of one of the pairs
j                                        Join the result of the above on newlines, implicit print
```

If the output format is flexible enough to remove the need for spaces, -5 bytes to replace `" = "` with `\=` and `", "` with `\,`

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 131

```
p[]=return()
p((x,y,z):s)=do print$show x++" = "++show y++"^"++show z;p s
main=p [(x,y,z)|x<-[2..2^12],y<-[2..x],z<-[2..x],x==y^z]
```

Comment: powers that have the same value are supposed to be on the same line

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript, 148 chars

```
s=''
for(i=2;i<4097;i++){q=''
for(a=2;a<65;a++)for(b=2;b<13;b++)if(Math.pow(a,b)==i)q+=a+'^'+b+', '
if(q)s+=i+' = '+q.slice(0,-2)+"\n"}alert(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6) 134 <s>127</s>

**Edit** revised, bugfixed and shortened
**Edit 2**After some research, I realized that this answer was invalid for chronological reasons. The question predates `arrow functions` by years.

All that said, the other JS answers are way too complicated

```js
/* for TEST:redefine console.log */ console.log=x=>O.innerHTML+=x+'\n';

for(l=[],b=1;++b<65;)for(e=2,r=b;(r*=b)<4197;)(l[r]=l[r]||[]).push(b+'^'+e++);l.some(function(v,i){console.log(i+' = '+v.join(', '))})
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: If you don't care too much about '=' formatting, then you can reduce down to 121 bytes: for(l=[],b=1;++b<65;)for(e=2,r=b;(r*=b)<4197;)(l[r]=l[r]||[]).push(b+'^'+e++);l.map((v,i)=>console.log(i+'='+v.join\`, \`))

Comment: @molarmanful there are strict requirements about formatting

Comment: Oh well... at least change the v.join part. That can at least bring the byte count down to 123.

Comment: @molarmanful at time this challenge (and this answer!) were posted, template strings were not implemented in any browser: Firefox was the first - rel 34, dec first 2014 - then Chrome, march 2015. You cannot use a feature that was available 3 years after the question

Comment: Oh well... I did not know that. I just got into ES6 a week ago!

Answer (score 0):

## C 184

Should compile (with warnings) with any C compiler

```c
char*l[5000],*t=l+4100,*u;
main(b,e,r) 
{
  for(;++b<65;)
    for(e=2,r=b;(r*=b)<4100;l[r]=u)
      t+=1+sprintf(u=t,"%s, %d^%d",l[r]?l[r]:"",b,e++);
  for(r=1;++r<4097;)
    l[r]&&printf("%d =%s\n",r,l[r]+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pyth, 55 chars

```
=Tr2 64V^2 12JYFZTFbTIqN^ZbaJj\^[Zb))))IJjk[Nd\=dj", "J
```

My first time using Pyth, so it can probably be improved. It's a brute force that checks up to 64^64, thus is quite slow. You can save time by only checking up to 64^12 but it would cost a byte.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 36 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
2žxŸãΣ`m}99£.γ`m}εн`m'=yε'^ý}„, ý)}»
```

I have the feeling this can be improved a bit by using a slightly different approach..

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ATwAw/9vc2FiaWX//zLFvnjFuMOjzqNgbX05OcKjLs6zYG19zrXQvWBtJz15zrUnXsO9feKAniwgw70pfcK7//8)

**Explanation:**

```python
2žxŸ           # Create a list in the range [2,64]
    ã          # Create each possible pair by taking the cartesian product with itself
Σ`m}           # Sort these `a,b`-pairs by their result of `a ** b`
    99£        # Only leave the first 99 pairs
       .γ`m}   # And then group the `a,b`-pairs by their result of `a ** b`
ε              # Now map each list of pairs `y` to:
 н             #  Take the first pair of list `y`
  `m           #  Take the `a ** b` value
 '=           '#  Push character "=" to the stack
 yε            #  Inner map over the pairs of list `y`:
   '^ý        '#   Join each pair with a "^" delimiter
      }„, ý    #  After the inner map: join these strings with a ", " delimiter
 )             #  Wrap all values on the stack into a list
}»             # After the outer map: join every inner list by spaces,
               # and the outer list by newlines (and output the result implicitly)
```